# Why null reference exception when binding data sources?

Tags: c#, binding, datasource

I am trying to bind data from object to my binding source.

I wrote this:

```
if (input.PhysicalCharacteristics.Mass != null)
   massBindingSource.DataSource = input.PhysicalCharacteristics.Mass;
```

but it threw me a Null exception.

Where could be the problem? When I debug it I can see that Mass is not null - but it must be to get inside this condition - but when it is trying to set data source on my binding source it fails. What's wrong?

Comment: Do the DataItems (columns) you are using in massBindingSource exist in the object you are assigning?

Comment: some of them are set to null  - for example in this input.physicalCharacteristic.Mass.Value = null - but I have textBox called Value, that uses data from data binding source. Is this a problem?

Comment: NULL should't be a problem. Can you try massBindingSource.DataBind(); as Brett suggested?

Comment: @Akhil - if he were to do a `.ToString()` on the databound object that was null could cause problems though...

Comment: @Brett - yea, ur right. @Martin: are you assigning the Textbox value something like Value='<%# Bind("Value") %>' or assigning in codebehind?

Comment: @Martin is this an asp.net application?

Comment: @Bala R - Thanks for asking that, I know that's all I've been considering it to be...

Comment: no its xml file, that I am parsing

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you're binding too, in the .ascx/.aspx do all of the properties that you're trying to access of `input.PhysicalCharacteristics.Mass` exist? And are they null?

Edit: from what your comment said, if they are null, I've always assigned an empty string to the `textBox.Text` This could be accomplished by something like: (I think this should work).

```
textBox.Text = '<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Value") ?? "" %>'
```

Comment: you think not calling `DataBind()` is causing the `NullReferenceException` ?

Comment: @Bala R - if the null reference exception was happening on the .ascx/.aspx side, then it could, right?

Comment: I don't see how not calling `DataBind()` can the exception; besides we don't even know if it's a asp.net exception (usually, but not necessarily, binding datasource is used in winforms applications).

Comment: they are null, but not always - some time, they could have same value, but in some cases its there, so I have to show it

Answer (score 0):

Convert Mass' data-type to Massbindingsource's acceptable data-type.